# iOS7 - what kind of In-App purchase is this?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, in-app-purchase, subscription

- The IAP never expires. It is linked to a UUID in a KeyChain. The UUID is used in a database and other places as an identifer, and is critical to functionality.
- If they upgrade to a newer iPhone and reuse the Apple ID, then the IAP follows them. The UUID shouldn't be changing in this case. Everything is cool so far.
- But I don't want the IAP to be shared across multiple devices sharing the same Apple ID. I want them to pay for the IAP because every new device with the IAP represents a cost to me.

So I'm at a dilemma on how to classify it:

- It isn't a consumable because you never need more than one and you don't use it up.
- It could be a non-consumable, however, those need to be restored based on Apple ID. Here I get screwed with the Restore Purchases requirement. Basically, any Joe Schmoe can give out his Apple ID to his friends, and everybody gets the IAP for free. I don't want the IAP transferred to multiple devices.
- It could be a non-renewing subscription, but it never expires, so they never need to add additional subscriptions. Can I specify the subscription lasts for a very long time (like 20 years) and limit them to purchasing one? The Apple guidelines aren't very specific on this.
- It's not an auto-renewable subscription for multiple reasons detailed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a non-consumable. If you expect the Apple ID will be used across multiple devices, just price your IAP accordingly to account for this.

Comment: Thank you. Apple really needs to let us use the UDID. It would solve a lot of problems!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure this question is a great fit here because it's not a programming question and nobody but Apple's app review team will be able to give you a definite answer. I do know that subscriptions need to be restorable across multiple devices, so I don't know if that helps you out. The only non-restorable purchase type you can have is a consumable.

I am also not sure that your logic quite works - let's say you store the UUID in the keychain. How are you deriving it so that it's locked to the SIM? You don't have access to the IMEI or anything that uniquely identifies the SIM card on iOS.

Comment: My understanding is that non-renewing subscriptions don't need to be restored. See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009 "Redownload an In-App Purchase". Maybe my terminology isn't right, but when I upgraded to a new phone, I just transferred the SIM, and the UUID was moved, too. Once I installed the App, I got everything back.

Comment: It is nothing to do with the SIM.  It is to do with you restoring a backup of the phone.  If you restore a backup then application data is restored - which includes the data in the keychain.  You could restore that same backup image to 3 phones and all would have the same UUID

Comment: @Paulw11 - Do you have a link or reference that the SecItems are backed up?

Comment: You have proved it when you moved to a new phone - the item was still in the key chain.  It certainly didn't come from the SIM because your app will work on a iPod or an iPad without 3G

Comment: Thanks, have removed erroneous reference to SIM in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You want to restrict the use to one device.  That means it must be a "consumable IAP" according to Apple guidelines (note - non-renewing subscriptions won't work - they need to be copied to all devices owned by the user).  So make it consumable but make it easy - sell the product as "5000 uses".  Each time the user uses the function or the App, charge them one 'use'. This also has the advantage that a heavy user may willingly pay you twice.

And…you can use bluetooth (MKSession) or iCloud to transfer all remaining uses from one device to another device to solve the problem of a user purchasing a new device.